# ReactQuery + Typescript how to type query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

hello why i have typescript error?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post title should be a clear, specific question without tags. Your code and errors should not be in images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LibraryContext.Provider` is expecting libraryType.

While react query the default value is `undefined`.

So you may need to do something like this:

```
const defaultLibraryValue = {
 name: '',
 address: '',
 phone: ''
//Add a default to each property of libraryType
} as libraryType; 

<LibraryContext.Provider value ={{library: data === undefined ? defaultLibraryValue : data}}
```